# Contraints & Camtrack

Tags: constraints

I am trying to get a camera to follow a point in the X,Y,Z plane.  It worked yesterday, but I can't get it to work today.

I was able to follow the Book Tutorial, where he shows the setup steps: Add: (i) Camera, (ii) Empty [Camtrack], and (iii) [Ctl T] Track to Constraint.  No matter what I try today, the camera will not follow the Camtrack point?

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.
WFR

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so, don't forget to mark the Checkmark on the left side of the answer to let others know that it does solve the issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

### **Track To Constraint**

In order to use Track To Constraint, follow these steps:

1. Add your camera
2. Add the empty
3. Select the camera, then hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and select the empty -- this will make both the camera and the empty selected at the same time. You can tell if they are both selected because they should both be highlighted at the same time
   **NOTE:** The order you select these in is very important: **first** select the camera, **then** hold down <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while selecting the empty
4. Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> -> Track To Constraint
   Here is a demonstration:

   [image]

Here is a second, alternative method you can use once you have added your camera and the empty:

1. Select the camera
2. In the Object Properties panel, under the Constraints tab, set Target to the empty, as shown here:

   [image]